# This is only sending two requests

Tags: c#

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            var cookie = webBrowser1.Document.Cookie;
            foreach (string s in listBox1.Items)
            {
                var data = "postdata" + s;
                var req = WebRequest.Create("example.com") as HttpWebRequest;
                req.Method = "POST";
                req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                req.ContentLength = data.Length;
                req.Headers["cookie"] = cookie;
                using (var sw = new StreamWriter(await req.GetRequestStreamAsync(), Encoding.ASCII))
                {
                    sw.Write(data);
                    sw.Close();
                }
            }
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
        }
    }
```

So my code is supposed to take items from a listbox, and use it send a POST request. It's doing that, but even though I have hundreds of items, it's only running two, then stopping. I'm not getting any errors, so I don't understand what's wrong. I've made sure it's only running twice by putting a messagebox in there.

Comment: Are you receiving any exceptions? What are you doing to debug/verify it's only running twice?

Comment: Like I said in the OP, I put a messageBox under the request and ran the code. The messageBox only showed twice.

Comment: browsers have a limit to how many simultaneous requests can access a particular server; for IE, this has usually been 2.  You'd be better off sending this once as a giant json object.

Comment: Great. I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: @ps2goat he is not using browser controls to send the data.

Comment: Sorry. Web servers may have the same restrictions, due to Denial of Service attacks.

Comment: @ps2goat yes it possible that the server in question have limits but you will hardly see that until you actually hit some huge amount of requests.

Comment: @user2693030 try to properly close your request before initiating a new one.

Comment: I second the suggestion @Prix made.  Having worked with HttpWebRequests for the first time recently I was failing to close mine too, and it would hang indefinitely after the second request.

Comment: Are you sure it's not because of async? I did it previously without using async and it worked, but it was way too slow.

Comment: I third @Prix...what were you doing before async that used to work?

Comment: You can also try enabling network tracing in verbose mode to see what is happening with your post requests. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyb3xww8.aspx

Comment: I was just calling a POST request with a button. Same thing, just without async.

Comment: @Prix What do you mean properly closing it?